# JavaScript Array.prototype.fill: meaning of parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameters

The documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) indicates that the syntax for `Array.prototype.fill` is:

```
Array.prototype.fill(value[, start[, end]])
```

The example

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3].fill(4, 1, 1));         // [1, 2, 3]
```

in the documentation and my testing agrees with the commented answer.

However, I can’t see how that can be right. The parameters indicate that indexes `1` through `1` should  be filled with `4`. Index `1` has the value of `2`, so I should have though that the result should be `[1,4,3]`.

What is the correct interpretation of the parameters `start` and `end`?

Comment: `the empty string` string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log([1, 2, 3].fill(4, 1, 1));
```

First argument `4` is value to fill with.
Second argument `1` is starting index (where to start from).
Third argument `1` is ending index which is exclusive.

So if you do: `console.log([1, 2, 3].fill(4, 0, 3));`

It will start filling `[1,2,3]` array starting from index `0` (value `1`) and overwriting all values up to the index of `2` since we said `3` is exclusive.

So result will be: `[4, 4, 4]`

Comment: I think the key word here is _exclusive_. I get that. Do you have a reference for this? MDN doesn’t make any mention of this.

Comment: @Manngo You're right, they don't, I mean I'm not JS programmer really, my background is Java and the common case with methods where you have these `start` and `end` values is that starting value is inclusive and ending value is exclusive.

Comment: OK, I get that too. The documentation for `Array.prototype.slice` specifically mentions __not included__, which `fill` does not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you read [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) code, you will see following code:

```js
var k = relativeStart < 0 ?
  Math.max(len + relativeStart, 0) :
  Math.min(relativeStart, len);

// Steps 9-10.
var end = arguments[2];
var relativeEnd = end === undefined ?
  len : end >> 0;

// Step 11.
var final = relativeEnd < 0 ?
  Math.max(len + relativeEnd, 0) :
  Math.min(relativeEnd, len);

// Step 12.
while (k < final) {
```

As you can see, it says `while (k < final)`. In your case, both `k` and `final` holds same value and hence no mutation is made.

---

If you change the arguments to not being same, you will see the difference.

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3].fill(4, 1, 2));
```

---

As suggested by [skyboyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071697/skyboyer), same logic is shared in [ECMA spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.fill)

Also suggested by **skyboyer**,

> [...].slice(1, 1)

does not do anything. But

> [...].splice(1,1)
>
> "...".substr(1, 1)

mutates/ returns value. This is because:

> @skyboyer for Array.splice, second argument is not index but count. For String.substr second argument is length and not index again. Hence both work just fine

---

#### References:

- [Array.fill Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)
- [Array.splice Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Syntax)
- [Array.slice Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Syntax)
- [String.substr Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr#Syntax)

Comment: @skyboyer essentially, bounds of a loop should be different. If I say, you have to loop from one to one, there is no need for loop. In my understanding, the implemented logic makes sense.

Comment: @skyboyer for [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Syntax), second argument is not index but count. For [String.substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr#Syntax) second argument is length and not index again. Hence both work just fine

Answer (score 0):

In simple words

```
console.log([1, 2, 3].fill(4, 1, 1));
```

second and thid parameters are nothing but the length of the array to be filled that is calculated by subtraction in your case 1-1 is 0 so it will not fill any thing if you want to fill only second one you have to use

```
console.log([1, 2, 3].fill(4, 1, 2));
```